# unwrapping button.titleLabel.text

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I need to compare the text of a button with a variable.

```
@IBAction func CheckifATrue(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let thisbutton = sender.titleLabel.text {
        if thisbutton == theAnswer.text {
            score++
            println("Correct")}
    }
}
```

is giving me an error forcing me to put !! after titleLabel. I can't do this as there is a possibility (actually - a certainty) that the buttons titleLabel will be nil. Why does the if let statement not let me unwrap? is there another way to pull button text where I can safetly remove the optional through an if let and only execute code if valid?

Comment: how about using if let thisbutton = sender.titleLabel and use thisbutton.text in the if condition?

Comment: Great variable names!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change type of sender from `AnyObject` to `UIButton` after that you can unwrap it this way:

```
@IBAction func CheckifATrue(sender: UIButton) {

    if let thisbutton = sender.titleLabel?.text {
        if thisbutton == theAnswer.text {
            score++
            println("Correct")}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func CheckifATrue(sender: AnyObject) {
    let sender = sender as! UIButton
    if let thisbutton = sender.titleLabel?.text {
      if thisbutton == theAnswer.text {
        score++
        println("Correct")}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
It was actually a bit of both. I needed to change it to a UIButton and then also set thisbutton = to sender.titleLabel and only then an if statemenet comparing thisbutton.text to theAnswer.text. Posting the solution in case anyone else has this problem in the future

```
@IBAction func checkifCTrue(sender: UIButton){
    if let thisbutton = sender.titleLabel {
    if thisbutton.text == secretAnsarrrrr.text {
    score++
    println("Correct")}
    }}
```